# Latex packages in Wordpress

Tags: math-mode, packages, online

Is it possible to use any package in a wordpress.com blog?

I see in http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/ that wordpress uses the packages `amsmath`, `amsfonts` and `amssymb`, but if I want, e.g., to make a diagram with `xypic` -or to use any other package, is there any way?

Comment: It's maybe better to ask in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that there are various ways that LaTeX-like syntax is used in blogs: some do use TeX, others use MathJax. It looks like WordPress.com might use a 'real' TeX system, but I doubt they allow arbitrary packages. You might want to look at [QuickLaTeX](http://www.quicklatex.com).

Comment: I second @Joseph's suggestion. QuickLaTeX uses a reasonable up-to-date TeX Live which means you have (nearly) every package available that made its way into TL.

Comment: Duplicate of [Latex packages in Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/82293)